# Hide gui dialog pop-ups from bash script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, gui, popups

I am running a bash script which executes a command that pops-up an annoying GUI dialog (I execute it multiple times inside the script). This pop-up disrupts whatever I am doing in the UI while running the script in the background.

[image: UI]

Is there any way to hide these?

Comment: Some more details, like which command is executed etc., would help.

Comment: It's a c++ binary from [this](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki) open source project. My bad, I just found a quiet option in the Wiki section for the command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

GUI applications executed from a script try to connect to the X server specified by the `DISPLAY` variable. If you clear that variable, programs will not be able to open a window, so that should effectively prevent any popups. For example, if you try to run this:

```
DISPLAY= xterm
```

You'll get an error like this:

> ```
> xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
> xterm: DISPLAY is not set
> ```

Either you can write `DISPLAY=` right in front of the command you want to run like I showed with `xterm` above, or you can write `DISPLAY=` on its own line somewhere earlier in the script.

However, some programs might not start at all if `DISPLAY` is not set.
If that's the case for the program generating the popup,
and if this program does something useful other than the popup,
then you won't be able to use this technique. It's worth a shot anyway.

Comment: Indeed, the program refuses to start in this case.